# What is the fish-like symbol in MediaWiki query API element

Tags: url, utf-8, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have captured an example JSON call that mobile Wikipedia app is calling. I don't know what the marked *fish-like* symbol is:

[image]

I thought that I can simply omit it:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json
    &formatversion=2
    &errorformat=html
    &errorsuselocal=1
    &action=query=info
    &converttitles=
    &redirects=
    &inprop=watched
    &titles=Noam_Chomsky
```

But, no:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "badvalue",
      "html": "Unrecognized value for parameter \"action\": query=info.",
      "module": "main"
    }
  ],
  "docref": "See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/postorius/lists/mediawiki-api-announce.lists.wikimedia.org/&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes.",
  "servedby": "mw1392"
}
```

What is this symbol that [`query`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query) uses? How can I type it (what is its UTF-8 code)?

**EDIT**: *As discovered in comments, the symbol could be `∝` (U+221D, *Proportional To*)? But calling the above query with `action=query=info` (no `∝` symbol) part changed into `action=query=info∝` (`∝` symbol present) does not change anything and the response is the same (second code block above)*.

[image]

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.

Comment: Maybe `∝` (U+221D,  *Proportional To*)? ∝

Comment: `info` is a value for the `prop` parameter of the `query` module, so that symbol seems to be used in lieu of `&prop=`. What is the original response (without 503)?

Comment: @InSync Looks like a typo as `&prop;` is HTML entity for ∝ (U+221D,  *Proportional To*)…

Comment: @JosefZ Ah, that explains it.

Comment: @JosefZ Hm... it seems that I have already done, what you are asking for? I have copied the entire text, pasted it into the question and formatted it as a code (first code block). The only missing element is the symbol in question. I could not paste it into question text, because I don't know what it is and how to reproduce it. I cannot copy-paste the entire URL because screenshot is the only source that have here.

Comment: @JosefZ Your idea of `∝` caught by heart, but unfortunately it is not working. I will update the question.

Comment: @InSync The original response is already given in question (second code block).

Comment: It doesn't work because MediaWiki simply won't accept it. The query is originally [`action=query&prop=info`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info) but was somehow parsed as `action=query&prop;=info`. Simply use the former and forget the latter as if it never existed.

Comment: @InSync Both (former and latter) returns the same error code. So far I did not discovered neither what is the symbol in question nor what is the correct example of the query in question. So far I did not manage to call a valid request. So "simply use the former" isn't a solution here, sorry.

Comment: By "*the former*" I mean `action=query&prop=info` ([try it using ApiSandbox](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specjalna:%C5%9Arodowisko_testowe_API#format=json&formatversion=2&errorformat=html&errorsuselocal=1&action=query&prop=info&inprop=watched&titles=Noam_Chomsky)). This will surely work, according to MediaWiki itself.

Comment: Using your URL (or correcting mine based on yours) surely works. But I still don't get _what is wrong in mine_. You keep telling that "_but was somehow parsed as `action=query&prop;=info`_" while there is no sign of `;` in my URL (the one that did not work; see first code block in question). There is also even not a single trace of `&prop` in this query, that you keep discussing with JosefZ about. So you solved my problem, but I still fail to understand what am I doing wrong or what is wrong with my query.

Comment: The correct URL has `action=query&prop=info` (`prop` is a parameter of the `action=query` module; see [the help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info) for more information). *Somehow* (I don't know how, but this doesn't matter), a semicolon was added between `&prop` and `=`, making the full URL `action=query&prop;=info`. Since `&prop;` is a valid HTML entity, which represents `∝`, it was parsed as such, resulting in the `action=query∝=info` that you saw. The only problem here is that you thought `action=query∝=info` is a valid query for MediaWiki, while it is not.